# Get the window title of a given .exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a `.cmd`- (or `.bat`-) file, how do we get the ***exact* window title** (containing *special characters* like `whitespaces` and `,`) of a given **.exe**?

Something like...

```
set my_win_title=
for /f "tokens=9 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq AnyApp.exe" /fi "windowtitle ne N/A" /fo csv') do (
    set my_win_title=%%a
)
```

...but with e.g. `;` or `|` instead of `,` as delimiter for the `.csv`-list because the window title in question contains a `,` itself, so the above code cuts it off, resulting in an incomplete window title only.

I already tried the obvious (simply replacing `,` with `;`), but it didn't work.

---

###### For your reference, here is the above code explained in detail:

- `set my_win_title=`: This line initializes the variable `my_win_title` to an empty string. This is done to avoid any previous value that might have been assigned to it.
- `for /f "tokens=9 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq AnyApp.exe" /fi "windowtitle ne N/A" /fo csv') do (`: This line starts a for loop that iterates over the output of the command inside the parentheses. The command is `tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq AnyApp.exe" /fi "windowtitle ne N/A" /fo csv`, which lists all the processes that match the following filters:

  - `imagename eq AnyApp.exe`: The image name (the executable file name) of the process is equal to the first argument of the batch script, without any quotes. For example, if the script is called with `AnyApp`, then this filter will match all processes with the image name `AnyApp.exe`.
  - `windowtitle ne N/A`: The window title of the process is not equal to `N/A`. This filter will exclude any processes that do not have a visible window or a window title.
  - `/fo csv`: The output format of the tasklist command is comma-separated values (CSV), which means each line will contain fields separated by commas, and each field will be enclosed by double quotes. For example, a possible output line could be `"AnyApp.exe","1234","Console","1","2,456 K","Running","DESKTOP-ABCDEF\user","0:00:01","My Window Title"`.
- The for loop uses the following options:

  - `tokens=9`: This option specifies that only the ninth field of each line will be assigned to the loop variable `%%a`. In this case, the ninth field is the window title of the process, such as `"My Window Title"`.
  - `delims=,`: This option specifies that the delimiter character for separating fields is a comma. This matches the output format of the tasklist command.
- `set my_win_title=%%a`: This line assigns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq AnyApp.exe" /fi "windowtitle ne N/A" /fo csv /nh') do set "list=%%a"
set my_win_title=%list:","=" & set my_win_title="%
```

The `set "list=%%a"` command get the complete output of `tasklist` because the `"delims="` option. For example:

```
set list="AnyApp.exe","1234","Console","1","2,456 K","Running","DESKTOP-ABCDEF\user","0:00:01","My Window Title"
```

The `%list:","=" & set my_win_title="%` is a *standard* substring replacement that indicate to replace every `","` substring by `" & set my_win_title="`. The resulting line is this:

```
set my_win_title="AnyApp.exe" & set my_win_title="1234" & set my_win_title="Console" & set my_win_title="1" & set my_win_title="2,456 K" & set my_win_title="Running" & set my_win_title="DESKTOP-ABCDEF\user" & set my_win_title="0:00:01" & set my_win_title="My Window Title"
```

So the last executed command is:

```
set my_win_title="My Window Title"
```

that gets the desired value...

---

Another, perhaps simpler method:

```
for /F "tokens=2*" %%a in (
   'tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq AnyApp.exe" /fi "windowtitle ne N/A" /fo list ^|
   findstr /C:"Window Title"') do set my_win_title=%%b
```

Comment: Right your first code worked, this is how we like it :-) Thanks, accepted your answer!

Answer (score 1):

- Use "/fo LIST" to select list output format
- Use "delims=" to select linefeeds as delimiters
- Skip all lines except those that start with "Window Title: "
- Pick the part after "Window Title: "

For extracting a substring from an environment variable, see https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

<rant>

Personally, to accomplish this task, I would use a programming language rather than scripting it.
</rant>

Comment: Good approach, helped me come up with working code, just instead of _start_index_ I did _findstr /b_. Thanks, upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

Two example scripts. Both create a dummy file with a comma in the name, start notepad with this dummy file, run tasklist to find the title of notepad.
The first only handles the title with one comma.
The second handles titles with and without comma's.
The code has some comments, but should not be hard to understand and adapt.

Example 1:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem this version handles only the windowtitle with one comma.

set "TestFile=TestFile with , comma.txt"
copy nul "%TestFile%"
start "" /min notepad "%TestFile%"
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
rem show results of tasklist
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv

rem the code that gets the title
set "my_win_title="
for /f "tokens=9,10 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv') do set my_win_title=%%a,%%b
set my

TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
rem cleanup
rem remove quotes for use in taskkill
taskkill /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fi "windowtitle eq %my_win_title:~1,-1%"
del "%TestFile%"
endlocal
pause
```

Example 2:

```
@echo off
setlocal
rem this version handles window title with zero, one or multiple comma's, the only requirement is that all values are quoted.

set "TestFile=TestFile with , comma.txt"
copy nul "%TestFile%"
start "" /min notepad "%TestFile%"
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
rem show results of tasklist
tasklist /v /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv

rem the code that gets the title
set "my_win_title="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('tasklist /v /nh /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fo csv') do set my_win_title=%%a
set my
rem strip the first 8 values
for /L %%N in (1,1,8) do call set my_win_title=%%my_win_title:*",=%%
set my

TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK
rem cleanup
rem remove quotes for use in taskkill
taskkill /fi "imagename eq notepad.exe" /fi "windowtitle eq %my_win_title:~1,-1%"
del "%TestFile%"
endlocal
pause
```